Using a LazyColumn inside of a BottomSheetScaffold in Jetpack Compose
When creating a BottomSheet with a nested LazyColumn, I am getting unpredictable scrolling results. When scrolling to the bottom of the list, then back up a bit, sometimes it will start closing the BottomSheet rather than continuing to scroll to the top of the LazyColumn.
How can I ensure the BottomSheet only starts closing when the LazyColumn is at the top position?
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun NestedScrollBottomSheet(
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {

    val scaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState()
    val numbers = remember { (1 .. 100).toList() }

    BottomSheetScaffold(
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(
            0.dp,
        ),
        sheetPeekHeight = 94.dp,
        sheetDragHandle = {},
        sheetContent = {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .offset(y = 1.dp)
                    .border(
                        1.dp,
                        MainBorderBase,
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(
                            topStart = 12.dp,
                            topEnd = 12.dp,
                            bottomEnd = 0.dp,
                            bottomStart = 0.dp
                        )
                    )
            ) {

                LazyColumn {
                    items(numbers) { number ->

                        Row(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .height(40.dp)
                                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
                            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                        ) {
                            Text(
                                "$number",
                                color = Color.White
                            )
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        },
        content = {
            content()
        }
    )
}


You can determine whether the LazyColumn is at the top using lazyListState. Based on this, sheetSwipeEnabled will be set to isAtTop.value.
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun NestedScrollBottomSheet(
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {
    val scaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState()
    val numbers = remember { (1..100).toList() }

    val lazyListState = rememberLazyListState()
    val isAtTop =
        remember { derivedStateOf { lazyListState.firstVisibleItemIndex == 0 && lazyListState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset == 0 } }

    BottomSheetScaffold(
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(0.dp),
        sheetPeekHeight = 94.dp,
        sheetDragHandle = {},
        sheetSwipeEnabled = isAtTop.value,
        sheetContent = {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .offset(y = 1.dp)
                    .border(
                        1.dp,
                        MainBorderBase,
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(
                            topStart = 12.dp,
                            topEnd = 12.dp,
                            bottomEnd = 0.dp,
                            bottomStart = 0.dp
                        )
                    )
            ) {
                LazyColumn(
                    state = lazyListState,
                ) {
                    items(numbers) { number ->
                        Row(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .height(40.dp)
                                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
                            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                        ) {
                            Text(
                                "$number",
                                color = Color.White
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        content = {
            content()
        }
    )
}

